# How to reduce time for a nested reading json file loop in python

Tags: python, json, optimization, networkx, nested-loops

```
G2 = nx.Graph()
count = 0

with jsonlines.open('filtered_data.json','r') as reader1:

for obj1 in reader1:
    count= count+1
    print(count)
    with jsonlines.open('filtered_data.json','r') as reader2:
        for obj2 in reader2:
            if (obj1["user_id"] == obj2["user_id"] and obj1['book_id'] != obj2['book_id']):
                G2.add_edge(obj1["book_id"], obj2["book_id"])
            else:
                continue
```

So I am trying to read a json file and create a graph. I'm using book_id as nodes and if there is a common reader of two books, then link them. If there's more books, all those books should be linked to each other.
Right now the problem is the code is way too slow. I have about 50k lines, and it will take more than an hour to execute. What are the ways to optimize this code
?

Comment: Difficult to comment upon without knowing the json structure. I'd try opening the files in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), merging the dataframes, and importing the edgelist to [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html)

Comment: FYI: Since Python 2.7, you can use a *single* `with` for multiple context managers. Also, `else: continue` is not necessary.

Comment: Please show sample of JSON files for [mcve]. You may be able to use pandas or numpy to parse whole JSON and merge data on values without looping.